# Cannot find symbol in java when i use object

Tags: java

when I execute it in command prompt, it gives error to height that cannot find symbol

```
class vol {
       int height;
       int width;
       int length;
}

class box {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
         vol mybox = new vol(); // mybox is created as a object
         mybox.height = 10;
         System.out.println(height);
      }
}
```

Comment: Is this really how your code is supposed to be indented? If not, why not [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45371371/edit) if you are expecting people to try and read it.

Comment: are those classes in the same file?

Comment: yes, both the classes are in the box.java file

Answer (score 1):

```
class Vol {          
    int height;
    int width;
    int length;
}

class Box {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vol mybox = new Vol();             //mybox is created as a object
        mybox.height = 10;
        System.out.println(mybox.height);
    }
}
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `System.out.println(height);` line. It should be `System.out.println(mybox.height);`